# No unique constraint matching given keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have two tables in in `PostgreSQL` -- `customer` and `creditcard`. A customer can have multiple credit cards, and different customers can have the same credit card associated with their account. However, a customer should not be able to have the same credit card associated with their account multiple times. Thus, in the `creditcard` table, the combination of the `cardnumber` and `custid` represents a unique key, which I want to use for the primary key.

However, I receive the following error: `ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "creditcard"`. Adding `UNIQUE` to the end of the `cardnumber` declaration in the `creditcard` table resolves this issue, but I want the same card number to be able to be associated with multiple accounts, thus this is not an acceptable solution. Most of my searches on this topic turn up discussions regarding foreign keys, but I don't see any issue with my `custid` foreign key. Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

**Note that this is not for a real product and is just for me to learn about SQL -- I am not going to store any real CC numbers with this setup.**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE customeridseq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 100;
CREATE TABLE customer (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY default nextval('customeridseq') --- this is a surrogate key (multiple customers can potentially have the same name...)
    ,username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    ,fname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,lname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,emailaddress VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    ,birthdate INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH NOT NULL
    ,passwordhash VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL -- assuming SHA-512 hash producing 64 bytes of data
    );

CREATE type cardtype AS enum (
    'Discover'
    ,'Visa'
    ,'MasterCard'
    ,'AmericanExpress'
    );

CREATE TABLE creditcard (
    cardnumber INT NOT NULL
    ,custid INT NOT NULL REFERENCES customer(id)
    ,cardtype CARDTYPE NOT NULL
    ,expirationdate INT NOT NULL
    ,billingaddress VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (custid, cardnumber)
    );
```

Comment: The error message does not match the SQL you posted. The SQL you have shown does not create any foreign key reference **to** the creditcard table. If the datatype `cardtype` is removed the SQL works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3a9ba/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: the comaas are in front. For the rest I tend to agree.

Comment: BTW: the code worked here (Pg-9.1) ,after replacing `CARDTYPE` by CHAR(1). What is your version?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a database handy, but this is how I would layout the tables to allow a customer to have more than one cc, and different people having the same cc, but not allow the same person to have the same cc more than once.  The solution is normalization. There are different levels of it and typically you want to go to at least 3 sometimes higher depending on the needs. There's for sure some art and science to doing it right based on the situation.

```
CREATE TABLE customer 
(
    customer_id PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE creditcard
(
    creditcard_id PRIMARY KEY,
    cardnumber --UNIQUE
);

create table customer_creditcard
(
  customer_creditcard_id PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id,
  creditcard_id --UNIQUE (customer_id, creditcard_id)
);
```

Comment: For an 1:N relation there is no *need* for a junction table. Just a plain FK constraint will suffice.

Comment: @wildplasser: It seems to be n:m if I understand the Q right.

Comment: Yes, you are both correct. Sorry! In that case the junctiontable looks cleaner than the composite PK.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter -- It is not n:m, as the credit card entity is still owned by only one individual user. Two people (lets say spouses) may have two separate accounts but have the same CC #. They should both be able to add and remove that CC # from their account independently of each other. Thus, it is a 1:N relation, not an N:M relation, as the CC entity is not owned by more than one account.

Comment: @BSchlinker: I don't think I get your point here. Looking at JustBob's tables, which of them would you delete to get a 1:N relationship? As far as I can tell, my wife and I are two separate entries in the `customer` table, making this a N:M relation. Which I would model almost as JustBob, although I tend to prefer a composite PK to a serial PK and unique AK.

Comment: @BSchlinker: What you describe is a n:m relationship - with some restrictions.